# Dynamically Download XML Files From Website With PHP?

Tags: php, xml, database

We have a database hosted outside the company that we lease to track quotes and whatnot.  It contains a number of 'instances' of quote tracking that contain the historical data to walk through the progression of a given quote.  One of the options on the 'dashboard' that the website provides is a button that allows for the downloading of an xml file that contains the information about the quote.  Each quote has an index with regards to our usage of the website, but the website url for the display and download are associated with a different ID, so I don't see doing something like iterating over the ids considering they're not directly related to our database.

I'm looking at the possibility of using a web-crawler/stripper to grab the information from our specific subset from this site as html, but I wondered if there is a way to essentially scrub a website from our user account's perspective, open each entry under our account's control, and then simulate the pressing of the download button without having the set of addresses at the beginning?

I apologize if this isn't super straight-forward.  We're looking for a way for me to download 3000+ xml files without manually doing them one at a time.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Yes, you can use php to simulate most of faking a user interaction with a server.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are trying to accomplish. You are saying there are 3000+ individual pages that you would have to browse to manually and click the download button for each one, to obtain the data you need in xml format correct?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.  And most of what I've found is dependent on knowing the addresses beforehand, which I don't have.